# Loader/Spinner CSS with Span element

Tags: css, spinner, loader

I have a span element and can not use another. Through this span element I have to achieve spinner/loader functionality and I want behavior looks like given below-
https://codepen.io/supah/pen/BjYLdW

Following is my code which is not working as expected:

```
  <span class="spinner"></span>


  .spinner{
    display: block;
    border-radius: 8em;
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    display: inline-block;
    animation: dash 2.0s ease-in-out infinite;
  }

 @keyframes dash {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
```

Can any one help me where I am lacking?

Answer (score 1):

This is to Easy.

You need to modified some css, give `stroke: #fff;` into `spinner` class.

Please check and let me know further clarificaion.

Hope this help.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-105deg, #009acc, #363795);
}

.spinner {
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
      stroke: #fff;
  }
  .path {
    stroke: hsl(210, 70, 75);
    stroke-linecap: round;
    animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 150;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
    stroke-dashoffset: -35;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
    stroke-dashoffset: -124;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <circle class="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5"></circle>
</svg>
```

Yes you can also create with pure css like that.

Hope this help.

```css
.lds-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.lds-ring span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.lds-ring span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.45s;
}
.lds-ring span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.lds-ring span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.15s;
}
@keyframes lds-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-ring">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

Yes, you need to change animation css like: `animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) infinite;`

Hope this help.

```css
span {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 51px;
    height: 51px;
    margin: 6px;
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) infinite;
    border-color: #000 #000 #000 transparent;
}

@keyframes lds-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Comment: Hey jaydeep as I asked in my question I have to use span element only not svg or circle etc.

Comment: Yes please check my another snippet, This will create pure css. And hope to accept my answer.

Comment: It is close to my need but I can take only one span element and no div as given. So can you do with one span only?

Comment: Please check my previous snippet.

Comment: Jaydeep this time behavior changed as spinner circle is not shrinking/expanding.

Comment: It will happen b'coz of we are use only 1 span, And this is not possible using pure css.

Comment: Yet, my requirement is not fullfilled but I appreciate your effort jaydeep

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you were doing with `spinner--wholePageWithVeil`. But, it's not necessary. The bit you were missing was giving the border a width and style.

```css
body {
  background-color: #008;
}

.spinner {
  animation: spin 1s infinite ease-in-out; 
//  animation: dash 2s infinite ease-in-out; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  margin: calc(50vh - 1em) calc(50vw - 1em);
  width: 2em;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg); 
    transform: rotate(360deg); 
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="spinner"></span>
```

Comment: This is not exactly result. According to question owner.

Comment: So, don't accept it. Maybe it'll be of value to someone else.

Comment: The only answer that achieves the spinner with just a `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

The CSS animation commands are working perfectly but you can not see it.
 you need an image because you are not using `<svg>` and `<circle>` as they use in the example you have attached.

Note that the width and height of `.spinner` class should be the width and height of the spinner image.

Based on your code:
[LIVE DEMO](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=abd37b6a-e245-4b8c-8211-7eeefdeb64b8)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--remove comment to use jquery-->
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <style>
      .spinner {
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 128px;
        height: 128px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 5px;
        border-radius: 2em;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        border-top-color: #fff;
        -webkit-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
        animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
      }
      .spinner--wholePageWithVeil{
        display: block;
        border-radius: 8em;
        width: 8em;
        height: 8em;
        display: inline-block;
        animation: dash 2.0s ease-in-out infinite;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        100% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
      @keyframes spin {
        100% {
          -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
          -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
      @keyframes dash {
        0% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        50% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        100% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="spinner" [class.spinner--wholePageWithVeil]="wholePageWithVeil"> 
      <img src="http://www.pbrennan.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ic_progress.png" alt="">
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry jonathana, I can't change in HTML So only one span element with suitable class I can take.

Comment: @RiteshGupta Here is another example for spinner animation, this time with pure css, maybe it can help: https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=f84f7bb9-c9f1-4c3a-8f7b-f1c0218e0cb0